# Wordpress URL change and infinite redirect on permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently changed my wordpress blog's server and URL. Before, it was located at subdomain.website.com and now it is located at website.com/newurl. I copied over the files and database, and updated the site URL and and website URL successfully. Initially, the site seemed to have been functioning properly. Somewhere along the road, the server started feeding back an infinite redirect loop on blog posts only. I can properly view the blog's homepage, but when I try to access specific blog posts it enters into an infinite redirect loop. If I turn of permalinks, and use the raw url i.e. website.com/newurl/?p=232 it serves the page properly.

Any idea why my permalinks no longer work? I already tried turning off plugins, and it still doesn't work. I also tried resetting the htaccess file with no success. Any advice is much appreciated.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also, I am not sure it is relevant or not, but the wordpress installation is in a subdirectory of a magento installation.

Comment: Have you tried going into the permalinks screen and just saving it again?  This will rewrite all of the permalink rewrite rules that are saved in the wp_options table.

Comment: Sometimes it might help to visit the permalink page and just 'saving' it.

Comment: Can you also confirm you have no other redirect plugins in operation?  These will totally ruin your day if you've changed the URL entirely.

Comment: I tried resaving the permalinks, and also made sure there are no other redirect plugins...Still no luck. I should mention that the wordpress installation is in a subdirectory of a Magento installation i.e. magento here is here: domain.com, and wordpress is here: domain.com/subdirectory...Not sure if that has any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was a plugin titled "WP No Category Base" that was causing the redirect loop. Once I disabled it my website was functioning properly again.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check...

Have you updated the table wp_options? - There are two fields in there that need to be updated when migrating a website, the option names are siteurl and home.

Also depending on your server settings, you may have to manually update your .htaccess as updating your permalinks doesnt always update your htaccess, a problem Iv run into before.

One last idea, the ‘AllowOverride FileInfo’ directive may be the problem, the .htaccess needs to override the main httpd.conf configuration file and is unable to do so without this directive. (This fixed a problem I had a while ago when the postname permalinks ect were not working but using the actual URL was)

Comment: Hi, those fields were updated from the start. I think my htaccess file is okay and healthy (I've posted it above). Regarding the AllowOverride, where exactly would I add that in the htaccess file? I tried adding it in several places and it created an internal server error...

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings -> Permalink -> Select (Post name) and Save it. No matter it is already selected just do it once again. Goto your site and Refresh page and check urls again. This is a common issue occurs when you migrate in other ways.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this but it still doesn't work...any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't touch your htaccess file.

I have experienced this kind of stuffs in the past and only shows right after you moved wordpress to either another folder, a new domain, or when you change hosting.

To fix it, please correct your Wordpress Address and Site Address... I usually just addd/remove WWW and/or changes HTTPS to HTTP and vice versa

Comment: Van Leo, Thanks for the tip. I already updated the wordpress address and site address before, and it is still having problems...any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Next time you want to move a WordPress site, you can consider using a WordPress plugin to handle the job for you.

There is several plugins that can do this for you.

Check this one : [Golive](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-golive/7793291)

GoLive Features:

Automatically Export the Database from Source Server

Transfering the files via FTP automatically

Auto-import Database in Remote/destination server.
Update .Htaccess properly
Update wp-config.php file on destination server with the new credentials.

Replace the URLs in Database (Posts, Pages, Menus…), and keep auto-update serialized objects too.

Comment: I see you've recommended this on two different questions - if you're affiliated with this product, please be aware that we require full disclosure; see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. Thanks!